# iphone 4 update to ios 7 failed - cycles in and out of restart screen

Tags: iphone

IOS7 appears to have been installed on my Iphone 4.  It comes on, apps start but then the "restart screen" appears after 1-30 secs.  After another 20-60 secs, the "restart screen" disappears and the app begins where it had left off.

Just to be clear, by "restart screen" I mean a black background with centered white apple and a progress bar beneath the apple.  The progress bar lights up to maybe 1-3% but never any further (and sometimes less) no matter how long it remains in this state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent backup (and thus aren't afraid of doing a fresh install and restore), there are a few things to try - all of them involve putting the phone in a mode that makes iTunes prompt you to do a complete restore/update/sync afresh.

- Put the phone in [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1808), and restore it.

If that doesn't help:

- Try [putting the phone in DFU mode](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034) and restoring it.
- If you find the above instructions difficult to follow, especially with the timing between actions

  - just [download redsn0w](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/) (look for the download links at the bottom of the blog post)
  - run redsn0w
  - go to the DFU option
  - it will guide you step-by-step to put the phone in DFU mode
  - once that's done, restore it from iTunes. Although redsn0w is primarily meant for jailbreaking, it is *very useful* for putting a phone in DFU mode.

Answer (score 0):

What finally "just worked" for restoring and upgrading a jailbroken iPad 2: using another computer.

After all that research and fooling with hosts files and god knows what.

BUT ... sorry to say, that exact flickering meant I needed a new LCD.

Much cheaper, though, through a local independent repair guy. Or see ifixit.com.