# My address lines are missing from my address book in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Just upgraded to iOS 7 and thought all was well until I noticed that all addresses are missing from my address book. All of the other data is ok - name, email, phone numbers, but **no** home or work addresses. I've synched several times to iTunes. I don't use iCloud. I've checked setup. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restoring from a backup in iTunes? Or [a restore after putting the phone in recovery mode (or DFU mode)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103231/31743)?