# iPhone 4 buttons don't work

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

I was trying to free up some space to upgrade to iOS7, and after I deleted all of my music and most of my apps (social, games, etc), my Home and Sleep buttons stopped working. I'm stuck in Settings. I started the upgrade, hoping the software update might solve the problem, but the progress bar has not moved a bit. I've tried using Assisstive touch and I still cannot get to my home screen, power my phone down, read my messages, or leave Settings at all. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do a soft reset first. To do that, just hold the Power button and the Home button together until your phone restarts.

You won't lose any data doing that.

Comment: This is by far the best idea. If this doesn't work, the next step would probably be to connect it to a computer or take it to an Apple Store

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent backup with iTunes, you could try putting the phone in recovery mode (or if that doesn't help, in DFU mode) and restore it from iTunes.

See [this answer on putting the phone in recovery mode or DFU mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103231/31743) for instructions.

Answer (score -2):

Try turning the phone off but if that doesn't connect your phone to. Your computer log into iTunes and if that still doesn't work I suggest u calling apple and have the help you through the process or sending you a knew phone . All you have to do is call the number 611 and you will get a variety of options.
Thanks and good luck hope you get your phone fixed.